# Android Java: Can't figure out how to loop my VideoView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, loops, android-videoview

I have the following code. It takes a video from my raw resources folder and starts the video, I need it to loop the video when it ends but can not for the life of me figure it out after a lot of strenuous researching.

This is my Java code for the Main Activity.

```
package com.infernowebmedia.staircat;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.widget.MediaController;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private VideoView mVideoView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
     mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.staircatloop));
     mVideoView.start();

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I've seen people trying to use setOnCompletionListener's but whenever I try implementing the code suggested in their answers, I get multiple errors from Eclipse, not sure what i'm doing wrong! Please help me :)

~Tom

Comment: What errors do you get with setOnCompletionListener?

Comment: The error I get is "The method setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) in the type VideoView is not applicable for the arguments (new OnCompletionListener(){})"

Comment: Apologies, it seems I mistakenly forgot to import the MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
...
myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
    // restart on completion
    myVideoView.start();
  }
});
...
myVideoView.start();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

set to Looping true on prepardelistener class, then resume the video on completeListener class,
Please try this,

```
myVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                myVideoView.resume();
                }
        });

        myVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                myVideoView.start();                
            }
        });
```

Comment: With the greatest of respect, this question is nearly two years old and long since answered. Your answer is wrong anyway lmao.